# How to make menu stays open when i click on sub-page

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have accordion menu with field for collapsing and for clicking href link, that stays open when i click on parent link and taking me to another page, but it's closing when i click any sub-page from menu. How can i keep menu also open when i click any sub-page

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub > .holder').on('click', this, function() {
      var element = $(this).parent('li');
      if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
      } else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
      }
    });

    // Opens "active" Menu Item(s)
    $('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').slideDown();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #36aae7;
}
.has-sub > a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: right;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;
}
.holder {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 11px 26px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 11px 12px 0 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 65, 65, 0.24);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: right;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;
}
```

```html
<type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='www.DontHideMePlease.com'><span>Products</span></a>

        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Would love any help!

Comment: Looks like it's staying open to me.

Comment: It;s working only when i click on "Products" and stays open. But it's closed when i click on Product 1 link or Sub product link. I want it to stay open also when i click on those sub-menus.

Comment: It stays open for me when I click on "Product 1" or either of the "Sub Product" tabs. I'm running the latest Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Oh well it's not working on my page. Im running on wordpress and that's the only last thing i need to fix on my menu. Here's screenshoot: http://postimg.org/image/v8sryd857/
In the example above when i hover over sub-page "gaśnice", parent menu and sub-menu getting class "open". If i click parent-menu: "sprzęt ppoż" its takes me to that page and menu stays open, but when i click "gaśnice" it takes me to "gaśnice" page and menu stays closed.